# Android Studio: how to create a second debug build type

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, gradle, build

I want to create a second build type that should work exactly as the already existing debug type. Currently I have two build types: debug and release. The debug one can be run with a single click, and is automatically signed with the debug keystore.
I manually compile the release build through the `Build -> Generate signed APK` wizard.

So to clone the debug build type, I first added a second build type named "local" to the app build.graddle file:

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    local {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Then I created `app/src/local/res` and added some files.

Then I do a gradle resync and select the new build type in the left tab:
[image: build type tab]

Finally I click the run button and I expected it to just work. This [IntelliJ help article](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-an-apk-in-the-debug-mode.html) says the debug signing config is the default:

> *This means that if you do not configure an artifact manually and
>   select the Deploy default APK option in the Run/Debug Configuration:
>   Android Application dialog box, IntelliJ IDEA will use the predefined
>   values in the certificate for the generated*

Instead, this dialog is shown:

[image: run dialog]

When I click the fix button, it opens the signing config dialog for the whole app module. However, I don't want to sign this apk for release, I need it signed with the debug cert. Also I noticed that a new `assembleLocal` gradle task has been created, but it generates an unaligned apk. In this folder I can see the regular debug apks are generated correctly in their unaligned and final versions.

How on Earth can I just clone the debug build type?

Comment: You should accept the correct answer, for me it was *ivan.panasiuk* answer

Answer (score 39):

Also, you can make your Build type similar to debug using:

```
initWith(buildTypes.debug)
```

Here is an example:

```
...
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'URL_API_BASE_SERVICE', '"http://theidasworld.com"'
    }
    debug {
        versionName 'APP BETA'
        buildConfigField "Integer", "PIN", "0000"  
        buildConfigField 'String', 'URL_API_BASE_SERVICE', '"http://debug.theidasworld.com"'
    }
    inspection {
        initWith(buildTypes.debug) // keep versionName and PIN from 'debug'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'URL_API_BASE_SERVICE', '"http://inspection.theidasworld.com"'
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I tried setting up signingConfig signingConfigs.debug, I've expected it to work, but it didn't, your solution did it!! thanks

Answer (score 36):

You can specify in the `build.gradle` file which `signingConfig` should be used with the `buildType`.

To sign using the same `signingConfig` as the default debug `buildType`, use the following:

```
buildTypes {
    local {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    /* NOTE: the debug block is not required because it is a default
     * buildType configuration; all of its settings are defined implicitly
     * by Android Studio behind the scenes.
     */
}
```

If you would prefer to use a custom keystore located on your local system, use the following instead:

```
signingConfigs {
    local {
        storeFile file("/path/to/custom.keystore")
        storePassword "password"
        keyAlias "MyLocalKey"
        keyPassword "password"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    local {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.local
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, we don't include the signing config in the build.gradle as each team member has a different OS and keystore path, and a VCS sync would break other devs workspaces. But most importantly, I don't want to sign for release. It should sign with the same debug cert the debug config is using.

Comment: @MisterSmith Each build type is signed with a keystore. And of course you can use the debug keystore, check the first part of the answer. The important part of the answer is that you have to define the signing config in the build.gradle because the local build type is a custom build type and there isn't a default.

Comment: I understand that. But what should I write in the "local" signingConfig so that it uses the default debug keystore?

Comment: Should be enough `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug`. If it doesn't work add `signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }}`

Comment: It took me ours to find that signingConfig option which is implicitly set for the debug build. Geez.

Comment: If your app has sub-modules, the compilation will fail with this configuration unless you declare the `local` build type for your sub-modules as well. This can be more easily overcome by adding `matchingFallbacks = ['debug']` to the `local` in build type in main `:app`'s `build.gradle`. Gradle will then use the `debug` configuration for your sub-modules, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Looks like `signingConfig.debug` doesn't work anymore, and it's changed to `debug.signingConfig` now

Answer (score 6):

For Kotlin build scripts, the equivalent of the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964495/8583692) would be something like this:

```kotlin
android {
  buildTypes {
    create("local") {
      initWith(buildTypes["debug"])
      buildConfigField("String", "URL_API_BASE_SERVICE", """"http://..."""")
      buildConfigField("Boolean", "IS_CI", "${System.getenv("CI") == "true"}") // boolean example
      isDebuggable = true
    }
    testBuildType = "local"
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to this if anyone want to include a dependency in the new build type then we must add this inside the android block 
  ```val localImplementation by configurations.creating {
        isVisible = true
        extendsFrom(configurations.releaseImplementation.get())
    }```
That means there is no need to write localImplementation dependencies. It's inherited from the release build type.

Answer (score 2):

Other way could be using flavors, like so:

```
productFlavors {

  app1 {}

  app2 {}

}
```

Comment: Yes, that s probably the easiest way.

Comment: that's a good solution, but my problem with falviours that I will have buildType&flavors combination. What if i just want to switch between different debug environments?

Comment: You have the build variants on a tab. There you can choose the build variant.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to add is if you have added some debugging dependencies, like:

debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.8.1'

then say you want to add a new build type called "local", you need to add similar items like the following in the build.gradle file:

localImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.8.1'